# Images in question not visible

Tags: bug

In this question of mine on Stack Overflow [Sending Image Stream over Socket Issue - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058453/sending-image-stream-over-socket-issue-android) there used to be three images that are now not visible any more.

I tried to open the link on a new tab, and you can check what happens:

This is a working image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBFi7.jpg

This is not -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrOFc.jpg

What is going on?

EDIT.

This is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Comment: I see all three just fine; they are *meant* to be just partial images with grey areas, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Oh wow...really? I'm using Firefox 28.0 for ubuntu canonical 1.0. you?

Comment: Chrome 34, OS X.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I added a screenshot

Comment: Same here, OS X: fine in Chrome 34 while Firefox 29 is showing the error (after quickly flashing the image). Each browser has its own image rendering, and when created using the technique from that question, it's quite possible it's not officially correct. For some related background see also [Why does this PNG image display differently in Chrome & Firefox than in Safari and IE?](http://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a/)